# Should we prefer temporary variables over user defined variables in c++

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

Lets say there is a c++ function foo() which returns a boolean.

I call this functions to check the status of a property
Or to get the result of the function call.

So what would be the best way to call this type of functions.

Method 1 :

```
bool flag = foo()
if (flag)
{
   // some code
}
else
{
   // else some code
}
```

Method 2:

```
if ( foo() )
{
   // some code
}
else
{
   // some code
}
```

**My Question**: Does using the temporary variable gives compiler opportunity to better optimize in general.

Comment: The compiler is likely to do exactly the same thing in both cases. It still has to use a temporary to store the result of foo before testing it.

Comment: @gandaliter In all likelyhood, the compiler will return the `bool` in a register, and test against that directly.  Without optimization, I expect that the first version would also result in an additional variable on the stack, but the real reason to prefer the second form is that it is more readable and more easily understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let us remember than a compiler does not have the same view of the source code as we do: *syntax* does not matter to it, only semantics. As such, we could argue it has a rather *symbolic* view of the code.

Furthermore, when the optimizer comes into to play, it will apply analyses and transformations that will turn *equivalent* symbolic executions into the *equivalent* binary.

Therefore, what matters for optimization is *semantics*. There are 3 different syntactic forms that can be used for an `if` statement:

```
// with a temporary
if (make()) { ... } else { ... }

// with a variable already in scope
auto var = make();
if (var) { ... } else { ... }

// with a new variable
if (auto var = make()) { ... } else { ... }
```

The latter syntax is desugared to:

```
{ auto var = make(); if (var) { ... } else { ... } }
```

There is a semantic difference: the scope of those variables differ.

- in the temporary case, its lifetime ends before the `if` or `else` block is executed
- in the named variable case, its lifetime ends at the end of its scope, *after* the `else` thus

In general, the difference of lifetime should be negligible, semantically. There are some cases though where it might matter: if you need to access it or if the side effects need be properly sequenced.

There might be some effects on the emitted code:

- for a built-in type: it is unlikely there will be any effect
- for a POD type: it might not be optimized as clearly
- for a non-POD type: the side-effects in the destructor (such as releasing memory) may inhibit optimizations

And which optimizations ?

Well, the primary optimization that could be applied here is *stack reuse*, whenever an object's lifetime has ended the compiler should be free to reuse its memory space for another object (see [`-fstack-reuse`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html)).

If the compiler cannot prove the object is no longer used, or must keep it alive because of side-effects in its destructors, then it might have to occupy more space on the stack for this object. As mentioned, it's unlikely this will occur (with optimizations turned on) when it comes to built-in types, but with a `std::string` unfortunately I would not be surprised.

Comment: the word "stact reuse" answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I normally go for the second unless I need to reuse the flag. It is true that in some occasions it may be useful for debug, but I don't like to pollute the code with temporary variables that the compiler is able to handle by itself.

A workaround would be to put all method one inside a block in order to free the flag after the if statement. Extra work for no result: I still go for method 2.

Comment: Agreed.  If the value is only used once, in a very simple expression, then declaring the variable is extra noise, which reduces the readability of the function.  If the value is used several times, of course, put it in a variable.  And if both the function call and the expression which uses it are complex, using a named variable may make things cleaner.  But any good debugger will show the return value of a function, so that argument is a wash.  And generally, the less state you have, the easier it is to reason about a function.

Answer (score 4):

The optimizer will generate the same thing. Aim for readable, understandable code. I usually prefer the first option, because it's easier to debug (you can see the value returned in the debugger).

Comment: Hmmm.  Both of the debuggers I use (VS and gdb) will display the value returned by a function, so there's no argument there.  And the first version is clearly less readable, since it introduces extra noise into the function.

Comment: @JamesKanze how (short of looking in registries) can you see the value in VS? I genuinely don't know and would help me a lot.

Comment: In VS2013, it appears at the top of the local variables window.  (In earlier versions, it did seem to me somewhat random.  Which was one of the reasons I strongly preferred gdb.  But they seem to have got that part fixed now.)

Comment: @JamesKanze ah, don't use 13 yet :(

Answer (score 2):

For primitive variables, there is no big difference. Both of them cause to generate same machine code due to optimizations. In the first case, the result is reusable also.

But, if the returned type is an object with a destructor. Then, a difference comes in. For first one the object will be destructed until exiting its scope (e.g. exiting the function in your case) and for second one, it will be destructed right after evaluation in `if` statement.

Comment: Because he checks the return of `foo()` in an if clause, it means that its return type is some POD or pointer. No destructor is called.

Comment: @George: Not necessarily. What if the object has overloaded [`operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) or [`operator!()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) operator? As same as `ifstream file; if (file){}`.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the first method with slight changes:

```
const bool flag = foo();  // const myclass &cref = foo_returning_object();
if (flag)
{
   // some code
}
else
{
   // else some code
}
```

In this case I can reuse the returned value if required. If my temporary is a const reference, it extends lifetime of the returned object and no overhead (constructur/destructor call) is imposed on my program.

Also as other post answers, it is easier to debug the returned value.

Comment: I think you meant “it extends the lifetime of the returned object” (instead of “it extends the value[…]”). Tripped over it in the sentence and someone who doesn’t know about these semantics might have trouble to understand what you mean.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Thank you Jonas for pointing, I typed value instead if life. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation: if you use the value multiple times (andy only need to call foo once) or if you can give a very meaningful name to the variable, you should probably do it. If none of these are true, it's a matter of style/preference.

example (1):

```
bool flag = foo();
if (flag)   // used once
{
   // some code
}
else
{
   // else some code
}
bool other_flag = flag && bar(); // used twice: call bar (or not)
                                 // depending on flag
```

example (2):

```
bool foo_available = foo(); // "foo_available" is more explicit than "foo"
                            // and increases readability
// same code as yours, here
```